# Can static web apps access outside services?

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on a web app and I am now looking into hosting said app. This app is a client-side app for right now meaning that all of the work is being done on the clients device and it has no backend other than the web server giving the site to the user for the first time.

I was looking into Heroku but that seems expensive for my app. Then I looked into Firebase Hosting and it looks good but requires the site to have static content. For now I'm pretty sure my app fits that criteria but in the future I would like to have users sign up for accounts and then store the info they give for the app data in a database. Would do database calls to a firebase database make the app non-static/dynamic anymore?

I know I could use Digital Ocean or another server provider but I want to be able to have scaling done for me so I can just focus on the app and not the containers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to build your app with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) for user logins, store data in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), and host all the content on [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/).  You could probably write the code entirely in JavaScript to run in the browser, but if you did need to write some code on the backend, you could use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).